# Find how many solutions are to $(x-3)(x-2)=\sin x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find how many solutions exist to the equation $(x-3)(x-2)=\sin x$

Let $E(x) = (x-3)(x-2)-\sin x$.

$E(0)>0,\quad E(1,5) < 0, \quad E(3) > 0$

Because $E(x)$ is continuous and changes signs 3 times according to Intermediate Value theorem there're at least 2 roots.

$E(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$ if there're 3 or more roots by Rolle's theorem $E'(x)$ would have 2 roots.

$E'(x) = 2x-5-\cos x$

$2x = 5+\cos x$

How do I prove that $2x = 5+\cos x$ has less than 2 roots? Or did I do something wrong along the way?

Comment: It can also help to show that the equation has to have an even number of roots.

Comment: If $E'$ has two roots, then $E''$ would have a root. But $E''(x)=2+\sin x$.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function
$$
E(x)=x^2-5x+6-\sin x.
$$
We have
$$
E'(x)=2x-5-\cos x,
\qquad
E''(x)=2+\sin x>0,
$$
so $E$ is convex. Hence it can vanish at most twice.

Since

- $E(1)=2-\sin1>0$,
- $E(2)=-\sin2<0$,
- $E(3)=-\sin3<0$,
- $E(4)=2-\sin4>0$,

there are two solutions, one in $(1,2)$ the other in $(3,4)$.

Answer (score 0):

The analogy that you are using only applies to polynomials.

For example, let the function $f(x) = 5x^4 + 3$ 
and let $g(x)$ be a primitive of $f(x)$. Then we have that $g(x) = x^5 + 3x + C$.

Depending on the constant $C$, the number of roots will change.

Likewise, let $f(x) = \cos{x} + 10$. This equation does not have any roots, however, the preceding derivatives have an infinite number of roots.

Comment: I don't know what definition you are using of *sinusoid*, but because of the $2x$, the function is definitely not periodic.

Comment: First of all the $E'(x) = 2x-5-cosx$. You wrote $2x+5+cosx$.

Comment: What analogy are you talking about? You're giving examples absolutely unrelated to the matter of my post.